# Eigenstate of position operator after collapse of the wave-function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, dirac-delta-distributions, wavefunction-collapse

I am studying basic quantum mechanics in undergrad and have hit a wall.

I understand that if a measurement is made for position, the wave function collapses into one of the eigenstates of position, i.e. a Dirac delta distribution, at the point where particle is found. If the particle is found at $x_0$, the wave function collapses into $\psi=\delta(x-x_0)$

The problem is that the delta function does not satisfy the basic requirements of a wave function, it is not finite at $x=x_0$.

The problem also exists for other observables like momentum, where the eigenstate is not square integrable.

Comment: Why do you think it is a basic requirement that the wavefunction be finite everywhere?

Answer (score 3):

It's true that the Dirac delta function is not square-integrable, and so an ***exact*** measurement of position takes the position wavefunction outside the Hilbert space. In the same way, an ***exact*** measurement of momentum also takes a wavefunction outside the Hilbert space. Note the word "exact".

If you remember the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, this shouldn't surprise you - after all, a state with exactly-determined position has an *infinite* uncertainty in momentum, and a state with exactly-determined momentum has an *infinite* uncertainty in position. Clearly, **these states aren't physical**, and can't be the result of any actual measurement.

So what *is* the operator corresponding to the position measurements that we actually make? Let's look at the result that we get from such a measurement: "The particle is at position $x_0\pm\sigma_x$". The way that this uncertainty is characterized informs the shape of the eigenstates of this "physical" position operator; for example, when we say "the particle is at position $x_0\pm\sigma_x$", one possible meaning is that the particle is equally likely to be anywhere in the interval $[x_0-\sigma_x,x_0+\sigma_x]$. So the eigenstates of that operator would be:

$$\psi_{x_0}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sigma_x}}&\text{for }(x_0-\sigma_x)\leq x\leq(x_0+\sigma_x)\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

As you can see, the eigenstates of a "physical" position operator (you might also call it an "approximate position" operator) actually *are* square-integrable! I won't prove it here, but it should be fairly straightforward that, for most reasonable characterizations of an "approximate position" operator, the eigenstates are square-integrable. (Feel free to try some other characterizations of uncertainty - for example, what if $\sigma_x$ specifies the standard deviation of a Gaussian probability distribution?)

So this prompts the question: **If we know that real measurements don't correspond to the action of the position operator, why do we still use the position operator to make predictions?** The answer boils down to the fact that working with "approximate position" operators is cumbersome in practice. Their action on a wavefunction is typically much less elegant than the "exact position" operator, which simply multiplies the wavefunction by $x$. Since many parts of the machinery of quantum mechanics don't actually particularly care about square-integrability of wavefunctions (that is, if you handle them carefully enough), we can often get away with using the "exact position" operator as a handy idealization of whatever approximate position measurement we're actually trying to make.

Comment: I disagree. There is a precise postulate I'm QM called Luders-von Neumann postulate that describes the post measurement state for an observable with continuous spectrum. The idea is to use the spectral projections of the selfadjoint operator and the outcome state is not a Gaussian packet therefore. Alternatively one may describe the process with Kraus operators and the associated POVM...

Comment: @ValterMoretti I assume this means you are making an answer?

Comment: @probably_someone If the wavefunction prior to the measurement is $\psi(x)$, and if the outcome of the measurement is "the particle is somewhere in the interval $I$," then shouldn't we simply project $\psi(x)$ to that interval? Why would we replace $\psi(x)$ with something that's constant over $I$?

Comment: In line with @ChiralAnomaly, your answer makes the new $\psi(x)$ after measurement seem somewhat arbitrary as long as it has the right uncertainty. But of course there is going to be some actual probability distribution. Perhaps more detail could be added as to how this is determined.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that if a measurement is made for position, the wave function collapses into one of the eigenstates of position, i.e. a Dirac delta distribution, at the point where particle is found. If the particle is found at $x_0$, the wave function collapses into $\psi=\delta(x-x_0)$

Mathematical aspect:

Continuous position operator $\hat{x}$ does not have eigenfunctions in the usual sense. The problem is there can't be continuous infinity of different functions of $x$ that are square integrable.

Delta distribution $\delta(x-x_0)$ is a non-function concept that helps with remembering and doing formal operations on differential equations and integrals, but it is not a valid psi function in the sense of Born's interpretation. That interpretation requires square integrable function.

> The problem is that the delta function does not satisfy the basic requirements of a wave function, it is not finite at $x=x_0$.
> Although finiteness is almost always the case with valid square integrable psi functions, this is not a good argument.

Delta distribution is not a function, it does not have values. You can say delta distribution is infinite at 0 *in the sense* it picks value of other function when integrated, but this different than functions such as $1/x^2$, where it means *function values* diverge to $+\infty$ as $x$ goes to $0$.

Physical aspect:

No measurement of continuous coordinate can result in exact single real number, there is always some experimental uncertainty involved. All measurements are rational numbers, typically decimals with finite number  of digits. So there isn't really *a need* for representing state where particle is exactly at $x=2$ m or $x=\pi$ m or any other exact number, because this situation can never be accomplished. All the measurement does is shrink the interval of values that the coordinate can have, but the interval is always non-zero.

Comment: "*No measurement of continuous coordinate can result in exact single real number, there is always some experimental uncertainty involved.*" Isn't this just true of any measurement? Not just continuous coordinates?

Comment: No, if possible positions form finite set of sites (labeled, numbered), precise enough observation can reveal which site exactly it is. A different example, measurement of spin component using magnetic field results in one of two possible results. There is always uncertainty in direction of the magnetic field in relation to lab frame, but ignoring that, atoms go spin up or spin down, nothing in between.

Comment: @JánLalinský In the example you’ve given the uncertainty creeps in in the confidence value of the measurement. What is detected as up isn’t unambiguously up (as ultimately we are limited by uncertainty principle).

Comment: True. I suppose I was thinking more in terms of perhaps energy. Where you know that that there are discrete levels, perhaps your measurements still have experimental uncertainty, enough so that you can't determine which discrete energy value your system actually "gave you".

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish one cannot (using the S-G device) find which spin projection atom in unknown state had prior to interaction with the device, but it is possible to *prepare* future state that is one of two distinct groups. In case of continuous variables, this "distinct groups" property is not present.

Comment: Yeah I get that. What I meant was due to initial uncertainty in the momentum, there’s always a finite probability of incorrectly categorising ups as downs.

Comment: @BioPhysicist it is not possible to measure energy of random atom with unknown history, but I suppose similarly to spin, one should be able to prepare atom to be in special state with energy known to be within uncertainty interval smaller than the energy level spacing.